# How integrate linkedin login or signup/signin with in codeigniter 3

Tags: authentication, linkedin-api, google-signin, facebook-login

I have already created a app with linkedin developers (name:my app) verified the page, added the scopes now this are changed previously we used (r_liteprofile r_emailaddress) now its changed into (profile email openid w_member_social) i am using guzzlehttp library.

I have tried all methods but all of them are old please help me. Can anybody share any latest or updated method that can help me.